# ReactJs down element getting selected when click on a popup dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table list view and its row edit option.

When click on the edit icon opens a popup with some input fields (dropdowns, text fields etc). When I click on the input elements in modal popup, based on the clicked element position, corresponding row in below table is getting selected.

How do we block the click/select events pass through below elements?

Comment: Please share your code. By the way do you have this anywhere in your css pointer-events: none;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your modal popup is the children to the table row element. When you click on modal popup the click event is bubbling up the element tree and as you have click event handler listening at table row level, hence that is also firing. You can stop this bubbling up by `event.stopPropagation()`. like

```
const handlePopupClick = (e) =< {
  e.stopPropagation()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click handler to your popup element that stops propagation

So something like

```
  <Popup onClick={(event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
    }} />
```

Please see the [React Official Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)